# Ошибка при POST запросе: name: 'PHP Warning', message: 'Undefined property: stdClass::$month'. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Не понимаю, в чём проблема. Нужно сделать POST-запрос на сервер (через fetch). Запрос должен происходить при нажатии на кнопку. Но когда я это делаю, появляется ошибка:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/latest_dz_web/calculator-yii2/web/api/calculate-price 500 (Internal Server Error)

{name: 'PHP Warning', message: 'Undefined property: stdClass::$month', code: 2, type: 'yii\\base\\ErrorException', file: '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/latest_dz_web/calculator-yii2/controllers/ApiController.php', …}
```

Код js:

```
const requestCalcURL = 'http://localhost:8888/latest_dz_web/calculator-yii2/web/api/calculate-price'

function sendGetRequest(method, url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
}

let chooseType = null;
let chooseMonth = null;
let chooseTonnage = null;

let body = {
    tonnage: '',
    raw_types: '',
    month: ''
}

function getTonnage(event) {
    chooseTonnage = event.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(chooseTonnage);
    body.tonnage = chooseTonnage
}

function getType(event) {
    chooseType = event.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(chooseType);
    body.raw_types = chooseType
    }

function getMonth(event) {
    chooseMonth = event.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(chooseMonth);
    body.month = chooseMonth
}

const headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}

function sendCalcRequestF(method, url, body) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: headers
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
}

const body2 = {
    tonnage: 25,
    raw_types: "шрот",
    month: "январь"
}

sendCalcRequestF('POST', requestCalcURL, body2)
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))

                function echo() {
                    console.log("body", body)
                    console.log("JSON.stringify(body)", JSON.stringify(body))
                    console.log("body2", body2)
                    console.log("JSON.stringify(body2)", JSON.stringify(body2))
                }
```

Кнопка в html-файле:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" 
                onclick="
                sendCalcRequestF('POST', requestCalcURL, body)
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
                "
                ondblclick="echo()"
                >
                рассчитать
            </button>
```

echo() - функция, которая выводит body в консоль (для проверки).

Причём с другим телом (body2) этот запрос работает нормально, и если выбрать значения переменных тела такими же, как в body2, то body и body2 получаются вообще совершенно одинаковыми. Но с телом body, переменные для которого не задаются изначально, а получены из клика по нужному варианту списка, запрос не работает.

Также прикреплю код html:

```
<div class="selector" id="selector_one">
                <div>
                    <transition name="tr" mode="out-in"> 
                        <span v-if="!show1" @click="show1 = !show1" key="raw_type">тип сырья</span>
                        <span v-else @click="show1 = !show1" key="select_raw_type">выберите тип сырья:</span>
                    </transition>
                    <transition name="tr">
                        <ul v-if="show1">
                            <li onclick="getType(event)" v-for="i in types"> {{ i }} </li>
                        </ul>
                    </transition>
                    </div>
            </div>

            

            <div class="selector" id="selector_two">
                <div>
                    <transition name="tr" mode="out-in"> 
                        <span v-if="!show2" @click="show2 = !show2" key="raw_type">месяц</span>
                        <span v-else @click="show2 = !show2" key="select_raw_type">выберите месяц:</span>
                    </transition>
                    <transition name="tr">
                        <ul v-if="show2">
                            <li onclick="getMonth(event)" v-for="j in months"> {{ j }} </li>
                        </ul>
                    </transition>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="selector" id="selector_sri">
                <div>
                    <transition name="tr" mode="out-in"> 
                        <span v-if="!show3" @click="show3 = !show3" key="raw_type">тоннаж</span>
                        <span v-else @click="show3 = !show3" key="select_raw_type">выберите тоннаж:</span>
                    </transition>
                    <transition name="tr">
                        <ul v-if="show3">
                            <li onclick="getTonnage(event)" v-for="k in tonnages"> {{ k }} </li>
                        </ul>
                    </transition>
                    </div>
            </div>
        

            <div id="button">
                <button class="btn btn-success" 
                onclick="
                sendCalcRequestF('POST', requestCalcURL, body)
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
                "
                ondblclick="echo()"
                >
                рассчитать
            </button>
            </div>
```

И код ApiController:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Month;
use app\models\Raw_types;
use app\models\Tonnage;
use app\models\ApiCalculateForm;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

use Yii;


class ApiController extends \yii\rest\Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::class,
                'actions' => [
                    'get-data' => ['get'],
                    'calculate-price' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function actionCalculatePrice() {
        \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $request = (object)json_decode(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody());

        $model = new ApiCalculateForm();

        $model->month = $request->month;
        $model->raw_types = $request->raw_types;
        $model->tonnage = $request->tonnage;

        if ($model->validate() === false) {
            return $model->getErrors();
        }

        return [
            'price' => $model->calculatePrice(),
            'price_list' => [$model->raw_types => $model->generatePriceList()],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы через отладку посмотрите внимательно, что у вас лежит в `$request` или  в `Yii::$app->request->getRawBody()` и тогда догадываться не надо будет

Comment: А вообще попробуйте сделать не `(object)json_decode(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody());` а просто `json_decode(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody());`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский глупый вопрос, но... как посмотреть это в отладке?) Единственное, до чего додумался - сделать вот так: `return [ 'price' => $model->calculatePrice(), 'price_list' => [$model->raw_types => $model->generatePriceList()], 'request' => var_dump($request), 'Yii::$app->request->getRawBody()' => var_dump(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody()) ];` и попытаться отправить такой запрос через postman (с телом body2); в таком случае он выдал null и в request, и в Yii::$app->request->getRawBody(); но это, кажется, вообще не то, что мне нужно былло сделать?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482    ....